# Combinations with repetitions allowed, order matters, n less than k

Tags: combinations

if you are a Londoner you are familiar with the situation: When you rent a bike a machine will produce a $5$-number code made up of $\{1,2,3\}$. My friend said "oh, I had this number before", but I said it is very unlikely as there are plenty of combinations; when he asked how many, I got stuck.

So here is the difficulty: $k=5$ (number of combinations) is smaller than $n=3$. Repetition IS allowed as it can be a code of $11111$ or $12312$. The order matters as well, so the code $11112$ is not $21111$.

Any ideas how many combinations there is? Thanks!

Comment: Since order matters, this is a [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition).

Answer (score 1):

3 way to pick the first number, 3 ways to pick the second number and so on which equates to $$3^5 =243$$
After only 18 visits, the chances are more likely than not, that you will get a number you have had before.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the total number of combinations you are asking, then It's simply filling 5 places with 10 numbers? which amounts to ${10}^5$ cases.

**IF THAT'S WHAT YOU ARE ASKING**

Comment: And if you are allowed only three numbers $\{1,2,3\}$, this is $3^5$.

Comment: Yeah indeed. @mlc